# Postgres - Add new column to existing table

Tags: postgresql, psql

I want to alter table and add a new column. But I want also set `Stroage`  column default value.

I tried the following and I get a error. Any idea how to fix this?

```
ALTER TABLE main_workflowjobtemplate
  ADD COLUMN "ask_credential_on_launch" BOOLEAN NOT NULL STORAGE plain;

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "STORAGE"
LINE 2: ...OLUMN "ask_credential_on_launch" BOOLEAN NOT NULL STORAGE pl...
```

Here is the table schema.

```
awx=# \d+ main_workflowjobtemplate;
                                          Table "public.main_workflowjobtemplate"
          Column           |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description
---------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 unifiedjobtemplate_ptr_id | integer               |           | not null |         | plain    |              |
 extra_vars                | text                  |           | not null |         | extended |              |
 admin_role_id             | integer               |           |          |         | plain    |              |
 execute_role_id           | integer               |           |          |         | plain    |              |
 read_role_id              | integer               |           |          |         | plain    |              |
 survey_enabled            | boolean               |           | not null |         | plain    |              |
 survey_spec               | text                  |           | not null |         | extended |              |
 allow_simultaneous        | boolean               |           | not null |         | plain    |              |
 ask_variables_on_launch   | boolean               |           | not null |         | plain    |              |
 ask_inventory_on_launch   | boolean               |           | not null |         | plain    |              |
 inventory_id              | integer               |           |          |         | plain    |              |
 approval_role_id          | integer               |           |          |         | plain    |              |
 ask_limit_on_launch       | boolean               |           | not null |         | plain    |              |
 ask_scm_branch_on_launch  | boolean               |           | not null |         | plain    |              |
 char_prompts              | text                  |           | not null |         | extended |              |
 webhook_credential_id     | integer               |           |          |         | plain    |              |
 webhook_key               | character varying(64) |           | not null |         | extended |              |
 webhook_service           | character varying(16) |           | not null |         | extended |              |
```

Comment: Why do you use STORAGE plain anyway, you're using a boolean. I think you have to ADD the column first and then set the storage. Didn't test.

Comment: Yea any idea what is the second set command that I need to run?

Comment: From the manual: ALTER [ COLUMN ] column_name SET STORAGE { PLAIN | EXTERNAL | EXTENDED | MAIN }

Comment: Changing the `storage` parameter for boolean columns makes no sense to begin with. That is only meaningful for variable length types that can potentially exceed 2000 bytes.